# tutorials_example_trainer fails in debug mode (-c dbg)

Tags: tensorflow

The build for tutorials_example_trainer works fine in release mode (-c opt), but fails in debug mode (-c dbg).

Did anyone encounter this? It seems to be a bug.

The command I run:

```
bazel build -c dbg --config=cuda //tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer --verbose_failures
```

The build fails with the following message:

> /usr/include/c++/4.8/mutex(125) (col. 5): error: calling a **host**
>   function("std::**mutex_base::__mutex_base [subobject]") from a
>   __device** function("std::mutex::mutex") is not allowed

< some warnings>

> 1 error detected in the compilation of
>   "/tmp/tmpxft_00005e78_00000000-10_cwise_op_gpu_log.cu.compute_52.cpp1.ii".
>   ERROR:
>   /home/uriv/git/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:248:1:
>   output
>   'tensorflow/core/_objs/gpu_kernels/tensorflow/core/kernels/cwise_op_gpu_log.cu.pic.o'
>   was not created. ERROR:
>   /home/uriv/git/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:248:1: not
>   all outputs were created.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can workaround the problem by editing

`tensorflow/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorDeviceType.h`

and commenting out the following 2 lines of code:

`static tensorflow::mutex m_devicePropInitMutex(tensorflow::LINKER_INITIALIZED);`

and

`tensorflow::mutex_lock l(m_devicePropInitMutex);`

I'll push a proper fix to the tensorflow repository shortly.